# How to create a live template in JetBrains IDEs to create hook state in React?

Tags: jetbrains-ide, live-templates

I'd like to create a live template to quickly add a new state variable using React hooks in PyCharm for example.

I think I got something close to what I want (including state type for TypeScript):

```
const [$1$, set$1$] = useState<$2$>($3$);
$END$
```

But doing that with `count` for example, I still have to rename the function `setcount` for it to be CamelCase because I get:

```js
const [count, setcount] = useState<number>(0);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help @LazyOne. Now, I figured it out. Should I answer my own question?

Comment: SO says I should https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer#:~:text=If%20you%20have%20a%20question,on%20a%20Stack%20Exchange%20site.

Comment: But @LazyOne beat me to it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Avoid using numbers for variable names, use proper names. It's easier to read and reference them.
2. Introduce another variable for `set$1$`, e.g. `set$NAME2$`.
3. Then on the `Edit variables` screen, for that new `NAME2` variable just reference the original variable and use with `capitalize()` function.
   https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/template-variables.html#configure_template_variables

This way that intermediate `$NAME2$` variable will be used (transformed) but you will not be filling it manually and it will be skipped when jumping between edit points once that live template is expanded.

```
const [$NAME$, set$NAME2$] = useState<$TYPE$>($VAL$);
$END$
```

[image]
*(use proper abbreviation/description of course)*

Comment: Very close to what I did except that I put `capitalize(NAME)` in default value. Probably a lack of understanding so I'll change that. Thank you

Comment: The column does not really matter as long as it works well for you and produces expected result. At the and it is what matters the most. From personal experience: I have never tried to use "Default" column for such intermediate variable stuff. Because in my mind it's for the value that you _may still be_ changing .. while here you will not.